# Soft delete repository while keeping property private

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, repository

I have a set of Entity Framework (EF) based repositories, some of which deal with entities that can be soft deleted (not all of them can). The entities are auto generated by EF. So far I have:

- The entities that can be soft deleted implement the ICanBeSoftDeleted interface:

  ```
  public interface ICanBeSoftDeleted
  {
      bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- For these entities I use repositories that implement ISoftDeleteRepository:

  ```
  public interface ISoftDeleteRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, ICanBeSoftDeleted    
  {
      void SoftDelete(T entity);   
      void SoftDelete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
  }
  ```
- I also have a base class for these, SoftDeleteRepositoryBase, that extends RepositoryBase and adds the soft deletion methods:

  ```
  public abstract class SoftDeleteRepositoryBase<T> : RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, ICanBeSoftDeleted
  {
      public virtual void SoftDelete(T entity)
      {
          entity.IsDeleted = true;
          Update(entity);
      }

      public virtual void SoftDelete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
      {
          var entitiesToDelete = GetMany(where).AsEnumerable();
          foreach (T entity in entitiesToDelete)
          {
              this.Delete(entity);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This all works fine. However, this code is part of an internal library distributed to users who call the repositories directly, and I don't want them to alter the "IsDeleted" property, only read it or delete entities calling the method. Right now they could do that because the setter is public.

How can I change my code design in order to do this? I can't change ICanBeSoftDeleted and remove the setter, because then I wouldn't be able to modify it from the SoftDeleteRepositories.

Thanks

**Update:** for the moment I've solved the problem by removing the "set" from the interface and setting the value in the repository with reflection:

```
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty("IsDeleted");
    propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, true);

    Update(entity);
}
```

However this feels like a patch to me, I don't think it's solving the bigger design problem...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to keep the EF classes behind the wall and map to POCO's; or type them as an interface (that does not declare the setter) when handing them off to consumers.

The second option leaves the objects open to have the deleted flag set by reflection.

EDIT: Further analysis of the code that you posted leads to the following question:

Do you intend to give consumers of your API the ability to declare Repositories ?

It would seem wiser to expose only non-generic repositories - e.g. CustomerRepository, UserRepository, PurchaseRepository in your API.

The non-generic API then forms a clean boundary from which you can separate your EF classes from the POCOs for the API consumer.

Comment: The idea is to only expose non-generic repositories. The problem is, if the ICustomerRepository is public then the abstract class RepositoryBase that it extends needs to be public as well. This would allow people to be able to create their own repositories extending RepositoryBase themselves, which I don't want... any ideas around this?

Comment: I want to use the EF generated POCOs as the DTOs, so I wouldn't go for the first option. I thought about the second, removing the "set" from the ICanBeSoftDeleted interface and setting it with reflection in the repository. However this seemed a bit "hacky" to me... Would there be any performance concerns?

Comment: This doesn't prevent the consumer from fiddling with the deleted flag using the same technique that you did.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do it by checking whether the entity is an implementation of ICanBeSoftDeleted inside your RepositoryBase instead?

Using an extension from here:
http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/how-to-tell-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-in-net/

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    //http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/how-to-tell-if-a-type-implements-an-interface-in-net/
    public static bool IsImplementationOf(this Type baseType, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return baseType.GetInterfaces().Any(interfaceType.Equals);
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T> 
{
    void Delete(T entity);
}

public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsImplementationOf(typeof(ICanBeSoftDeleted)))
        {
            ((ICanBeSoftDeleted)entity).IsDeleted = true;
            //etc
        }
        else
        {
            //hard delete
        }
    }
}

public class Customer : ICanBeSoftDeleted
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class UOW
{

    private IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
    {
        return (IRepository<T>)new RepositoryBase<T>();
    }

    public IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return GetRepository<Customer>();
        }
    }
}

public interface ICanBeSoftDeleted
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Entities that can be soft deleted can also be hard deleted. The hard deletion method is on the RepositoryBase, and the soft deletion method is an addition only on the SoftRepositoryBase, so that only those entities can use it. So unfortunately can't use this approach.

Comment: So the users can call SoftDelete() which sets IsDeleted to true (and calls Update) but you don't want to let them set IsDeleted to true directly. Is that because you're worried that they might forget to call Update()?

Comment: No, it's because soft deleting something is not just that; I simplified the method for the example, but I also want to always log the activity, maybe do other stuff when an entity is deleted, etc... Basically I want to control the business logic around it.

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid DTOs and a business logic layer then I guess you could use public bool IsDeleted {get; internal set;}. And if the Repositories and Entities are not in the same namespace you could use InternalsVisibleTo

Comment: You can't set an "internal set" in an interface. As a side note, the "InternalsVisibleTo" assembly property is so that another assembly can see the internals in the assembly that is marked, it is not related to namespaces.

Comment: Oh of course. My bad. So visibility between namespaces not a problem. So how about creating an abstract class that implements the public interface with an internal set deleted method? I'll put that in an answer....

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsDeleted
{
    get
    {
        return this.isDeleted;
    }
    //you can use protected if you intend to inherit the property and override it
    private set
    {
        this.isDeleted= value;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here I describe the creation of a property which can be used to detect whether a property or functionality is called from a valid place.

1. You need a protected variable in your class where you want to validate the IsDeleted property. For simplicity, let's suppose it is a string and let it be called softDeleteKey.
2. You need a public setter for that variable, let's call it setSoftDeleteKey for now.
3. You need a private function which checks the validity of your key, returns true if it is valid and false if it is not valid. Let's call this validateSoftDeleteKey.
4. Implement a read-only property called isSoftDeleteKeyValid which will call the function described in 3.
5. In your IsDeleted property check isSoftDeleteKeyValid. If it returns false, throw an exception. If IsDeleted was successful, set softDeleteKey to an invalid value.
6. In your SoftDelete method call setSoftDeleteKey with a valid value before you set the IsDeleted property. If an exception occurs, then call setSoftDeleteKey with an invalid value.

I hope these ideas help you.

Comment: Making the setter private or protected prevents me from modifying its value in the SoftDelete() method of the repository.

Comment: Then you can create a bool property which would be true if and only if setting IsDeleted is a valid operation. In your IsDeleted property forget about the protected keyword and throw and exception in the setter if the setter was called from an invalid place. Implement an InvalidReferenceToIsDeleteSetterException and throw that...

Comment: How can I do that? The method will be called from both inside the assembly and outside of it by external tools that reference it. Could you show some example code?

Comment: @chuwik, I have edited my answer with the description of the bool property mentioned in my previous message.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! However, reflection still looks like a cleaner solution to me in this case.

Comment: @chuwik, exactly how do you intend to use reflection in this case to solve your problem? You want to filter out invalid calls, so you need to implement the properties and methods for these. Of course, you can inherit your classes and overwrite these properties and then can use reflection to determine the class and the method, but the core of the solution is, of course the validation.

Comment: You can call SetValue there by reflection, but you need a validation to prevent others calling SetValue from other locations using reflection. The validation part is independent from reflection, it is the solution to your problem. You then can call the validation in the way you prefer or need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public interface ICanBeSoftDeleted
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; }
}

public abstract class CanBeSoftDeleted : ICanBeSoftDeleted
{
    private bool _IsDeleted;
    public bool IsDeleted
    {
        get { return _IsDeleted; }
    }

    internal void SetIsDeleted(bool value) { _IsDeleted = value; }
}
```

Then the models can inherit from the abstract class instead